# List<Objects> to Json File

Tags: java, json, jackson

Having an Object *Field* with 4 fields like String, Integer and Date (timestamp).Then a List of these objects.

Need to write a file in json format, that maps the **list** of objects.I will be updating each object on the json file independently.

Which would be the best approach to do this? I've played with ObjectMapper but can't achieve this.

Tried this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();// this is Jackson
File file = new File("/parameter.json");
Map<String,Integer> parameters = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for(Parameter par : Parameter.values()){
parameters.put(par.getName(),par.getValue1());
}
mapper.writeValue(file, parameters);
```

Comment: Use something like [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) for this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use Jackson. First you should create an object to keep all those fields. Object should have getter/setter methods. Then you can use ObjectMapper to write to a file.

Sample code:

```
public class NewMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

            mapper.writeValue(new File("/parameter.json"), new YourObject(1, "some string", "another string"));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class YourObject {

    private int a;
    private String b;
    private String c;

    public YourObject(int a, String b, String c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(String b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public String getC() {
        return c;
    }

    public void setC(String c) {
        this.c = c;
    }
```

And output is

```
{"a":1,"b":"some string","c":"another string"}
```